# Outlook Web Access Plugin Development

Tags: plugins, outlook, exchange-server

Has anybody written a plugin for outlook web access?  Are there any resources to which you could point me or tips you can pass on?  I'm probably more interested in OWA 2007 than 2003 but whatever you've got would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can customise to an extent (first link lists what is supported) there are hacks around playing with the client side scripts. You also can pull parts from OWA and intergrate them in you own pages, which sometimes is easier the place to start.

MS suported stuff 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891803.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996029.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996007.aspx